# My RecyclerView doesnt update on Notify Methods

Tags: android, multithreading, android-recyclerview

please read before marking it as a duplicate! :)

I converted a listview to recyclerview in my app. But the problem is that it just doesnt update when I call any notify methods. I read that i should call these methods on the Ui Thread. but even that isn't working. The data list has the item added to it but it doesnt get shown on UI.

Here's the code.

Adapter:

```
public class CustomViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

Activity activity;
ArrayList<Leg> data;

public CustomViewAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Leg> d) {
    super();
    activity = a;
    data = d;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Leg tempValues = data.get(position);
    return tempValues.getLegType();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    switch (viewType) {
        case 1:
            //...type 1
        case 2:
            //...type 2
        default:
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cell_leg, parent, false);
            return new LegViewHolder1(v);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Leg tempValues = data.get(position);

    //.... Simple view logic that correctly displays
}

class LegViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    //... Holder of another type
}

class LegViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @InjectView(R.id.leg_add_button)
    RelativeLayout legAddIcon;

    public AddLegViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, v);

        legAddIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Add Debug", "AddIcon clicked");

                Leg leg = new Leg();
                leg.setLegType(Constants.LEG);

                data.add((data.size() - 1), leg);

                refreshList("add", (data.size() - 1)); /// was using notify previously here
            }
        });

    }
}

public void refreshList(final String type, final int position) {
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (type.equals("update")) {
                notifyItemChanged(position);
            } else if (type.equals("remove")) {
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
            } else if (type.equals("add")) {
                notifyItemInserted(position);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Here's the Activity:

```
public class LegActivity extends BaseActivity {

CustomViewAdapter adapter;
LoadTask loadTask = null;
ArrayList<Leg> legsList;

@InjectView(R.id.leg_list)
RecyclerView legList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...boiler plate code

    legList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    legList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    loadTask = new LoadTask(this);
    loadTask.execute();
}

class LoadTask extends RoboAsyncTask<Boolean> {

    protected LoadTask(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // show loader
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        //load some data the send boolean for success

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSuccess(Boolean success) {
    //checking for success and loading data to legslist.

    adapter = new CustomViewAdapter(LegActivity.this, legsList);
    legList.setAdapter(new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(adapter));
    legList.setItemAnimator(new SlideInLeftAnimator());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onException(Exception e) {
        // other code....
    }
}
```

}

The problem is that the object is added to the actual legList when i click on the add button. I verified that but the notify notifyItemInserted doesnt seem to work. I tried running that on the UI thread but even that didnt seem to work.

Any suggestions? I followed the android recyclerview sample. Maybe i have used the RunOnUiThread incorrectly?

Also if you spot any syntax errors due to name changes, that isnt the problem, on Android Studio the code is error free.

Comment: You said there's no syntax errors on your machine, but it may be helpful to present us with an error-free piece of code as well :) In your `refreshList()` method you use `adapter` that is the activity's field.

Comment: Also i think the problem is due to some logical mistake. i cant paste the complete code because it'll be too long and too off-topic :/

Any reason why recyclerview isnt updating?

Comment: Trying to figure out... In my practice, I've never needed to call `runOnUiThread` explicitly in adapter to make these changes work.

Comment: Except for this, it loads and displays initial data ok?

Comment: when i was using 'listview' the code was working perfectly well. Also the problem is the data list does get updated. but that change isnt reflected on ui for some reason.

I can post the complete code but too many view logic conditions and stuff.

Comment: @Android777 yes initial data loads perfectly. It even enters the Add button click listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will take a shot and say it's because of this custom animating adapter:

`legList.setAdapter(new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(adapter));`

Try it this way:

```
adapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(new CustomViewAdapter(LegActivity.this, legsList));
legList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Although the above didnt work, but the problem was indeed with the custom animation adapter! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! :)

All i did was remove the anim adapter for now

Comment: @AmmarAmjad glad you resolved your problem :) just of interest, because I also know this library and used parts of it in my projects: are those notification methods not implemented in `AlphaInAnimationAdapter` or is it something different with it?